# What's the best way to keep status of comment object?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, entity, comments

I have some web application for placement on external sites. This application is a widget for comments like disqus (disqus.com).

Each comment it's a entity object with fields: "author", "body", "time" and etc.
In additional to these fields comment object has field with name "active"
That is:

```
@Entity
class Comment {

    private User author;

    private String body;

    //... and a lot of many other attributes

    private boolean active;
}
```

The "active" field used to separate active and deleted comments.
If "active" == false the comment is deleted, if no it's active.

Very soon I will introduce a functional which allows to pre-moderation of comments.
That is user publishes a comment but until administrator has not approved it, comment still not active.

So the question is what's the best way to make it?

I see two ways:

1) Change "active" field from boolean to int and keep the status of comment,

for instance: 0 - pre-moderation, 1 - active (approved), -1 deleted, -2 not approved may be some thing else...

2) Leave "active" boolean field and added additional field for status

Comment: Sounds like whichever would be easier for you to do..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why an `int` - why not an `enum`?

```
enum CommentStatus {
    Deleted, Pending, Active
}
```

Edit: Also, try not to scatter your `enum` all over the place. Use your Comment class as a robust model, add functions for `isActive()` or `isPending()` -- whether you use one field or two, or whether you use an enum or an int, that's an implementation detail. Hide that shizzle, yo.

Comment: I agree with the enum advice, but I'm not sure I agree with the masking of the enum. Having a getStatus() method seems clean to me, and I would find logical to have some admin page displaying a checkbox with each status to search for comments. BTW, HQL and Criteria queries will have to use the enum anyway.

Comment: Well, Hibernate is inherently aware of the implementation details of the class. I prefer 'talking functions' over `x == MyEnum.SomeValue` everywhere. If there's a `CommentRepository` I'd like to ask it to `findActiveComments(Listing listing)` which I agree - would craft a HQL/Criteria query based on the enum. But that means that this detail is in two places. Not everywhere you need to make a decision around the status of a comment.

Comment: It all depends on the usecases. If you have to search for [active] [or pending] [or deleted] comments, having a single method with an EnumSet<Status> as argument is cleaner, IMO. Having both is probably the best solution.

Comment: Thanks guys but I still do not understand what's the best way to keep status of the comment - on two fields ("active" and "status") or only one field ("status" with all states)?

Comment: We're saying one field. As an `enum` - are you familiar with this? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html